# Is there a way Edge Extension can talk to local process /Native Proxy

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Is there a mechanism in Edge Browser which can allow Edge Extension to communicate with local Process or a native proxy.

I looked at Edge API roadmap but could not find anything relevant, link below

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/api-support/extension-api-roadmap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated (02/16/2017):

Edge team releases [guides for Native Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging), which will be available in upcoming Windows 10 Creators Update.

### Updated (11/30/2016):

According to [Microsoft Edge extension API roadmap](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/api-support/extension-api-roadmap/),

> Native messaging is currently in development.

### Previous:

**The answer is no at present (8/11/2016)**, however, there are many people [provide their feedbacks](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/13612338-native-messaging) and vote for [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) support, hope Microsoft Edge would take it into consideration.